# How can I create a useful labelling function for images from a directory?

Tags: python, image-processing, path, iterator, fast-ai

I am working on Jupyter Notebook with the fastai DataBlock and Dataloaders API to prepare batches for a neural network.
Currently what I've done is:

'''

```
path= Path('TensorFlow\workspace\images\mini_alphabet')'''
```

#created this path to the folder containing 20 images labelled A1,A2,A3,etc and 20 labelled B,B2,B3 etc

and when i use .ls() I can open and view the output in this form:

> [Path('A1.jpg'),Path('A10.jpg'),Path('A11.jpg'),Path('A12.jpg'),Path('A13.jpg'),Path('A14.jpg'),Path('A15.jpg'),Path('A16.jpg'),Path('A17.jpg'),Path('A18.jpg')...]

What I want to do is make a labelling function that iterates through the mini_alphabet folder, checks to see if the image name starts with the letter A or B, and then returns that letter as the label.
So far I've written this function:

```
def label_alphabet(fname):
    labels = os.listdir(fname)  # <this outputs a list ['A1.jpg','A2.jpg',...]
    for l in labels:
        if l[0].startswith('A'):
            return "A"
        else:
            return "B"
```

Unfortunately when I use this it seems to label every single image as A. What should I do differently here?
Also if I wanted to apply a larger number of labels (ranging from A-G), how exactly should I set up that code so it labels through all of them. I was thinking of iterating '''for i''' through a list of letters and returning labels that match the filename.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

try
`if l.split(".")[0].startwith("A")`
instead of
`if l[0].startswith('A'):`

If you want an array of letters you could use
`list(string.ascii_uppercase)`

Also put a tab between `for` and the code that follows from there